# If element contains the word X execute Y

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to use jquery to search if one of the elements contains a particular word, and if it does, I would like to execute some jquery code on that particular element.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Example:

```
if $('div').contains('Bird'){ 

      ****execute jquery*****

}
```

Markup

```
<div>Dog x y z </div>
<div>Cat x y z </div>
<div>x y z Bird</div>
<div>x y z Fish</div>
```

What I tried:

```
if ($("#producttabs2 #producttabs ul li a").has('iPhone App')) {
    $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
}
```

Comment: Check original post. Thanks;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use filter:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.indexOf(somestring) !== -1;
}).css("border","1px solid red");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('div').is((':contains("bird")'))
 // code here
```

You want the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Comment: Beware: .is() will return true if __any__ elements matching selector 'div' contain that text. Using :contains is a good option (although probably less performative), but better to use it with .filter() if OP wants to apply css to a subset of divs. Otherwise, every div on the page will get the css if even one div matches the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Simple jQuery:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if( $(this).text().indexOf('Bird') != -1) {
     //do something
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gDu5t/)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').filter(function() {
  return this.innerHTML.match(/bird/ig);
}).css({
    border: '1px solid #f00'
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x46vz/)***